# How to create a dataframe with two columns from seperate dataframes in R

Tags: r

I want to create a new dataframe with two columns, each column from a seperate dataframe, and then plot onto the same bar chart

Both columns are called OKS_score.

df1 is preopOKS, this has 645 rows and df2 is postopOKS, this has 643 rows

I have tried `left_join`

```
df3 <- preopOKS$OKS_score %>% 
  left_join(postopOKS$OKS_score, copy = TRUE)
```

I have tried to assign each column and `rbind` them: however this makes a DF with 2 rows of mulitple values.

```
x <- preopOKS$OKS_score
y <- postopOKS$OKS_score

z <- rbind(x,y)

str(z)
 num [1:2, 1:645] 36 52 20 34 20 31 33 45 29 51 ...
 - attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  ..$ : chr [1:2] "x" "y"
  ..$ : NULL
```

I have even tried to pivot_longer to make the df into a format I can plot with:

```
z %>% 
  pivot_longer(names_to = 'x', values_to = 'y')
```

As you can tell, I'm very new and can't even get my head around where I'm going wrong, with my methods, or my terribly basic code.

Comment: Do the scores in preopOKS correspond to specific scores in postopOKS? (Are they observations from the same individuals?) If so, `left_join` is a good choice, but you need to give it data frames instead of specific vectors, and you need some joining column (like 'ID') in each that ties the observations to each other. (`left_join(preopOKS, postopOKS, by = "ID")`, for example.) Maybe if you showed what those data frames look like it would make it clearer what you're trying to do.

Comment: Maybe thats why the left_join isn't working.

The two sets are split from an original DF. They don't all have a link. 

How is best to show the dataframes here? (new user, and relatively large dataframe!)

Comment: It sounds like the best choice would be to make a link column in the two data frames when you split them from the original, so you can use it to tie them back together later. You would just add an 'ID' column (or some other name) to the original DF with unique values for each row, then copy that to the two new data frames. Is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution, using the name "OKS" for the original data frame (which is used to generate "preopOKS" and "postopOKS") and assuming it has an "OKS_score" column:

```
library("dplyr")

# add unique id column to original data frame:
OKS$ID <- 1:nrow(OKS)

# assuming preop data frame has unchanged scores, select just score and ID, 
# but rename score so it's different from postOKS score name:
preopOKS <- OKS[, c("ID", "OKS_score_pre")]

# make postop data frame with whatever function is used to change score:
postopOKS <- data.frame(ID = OKS$ID, OKS_score_post = whatever_function(OKS$OKS_score))

# recombine them
finalOKS <- left_join(preopOKS, postopOKS, by = "ID")
```

It would be easier, depending on your use case, to just keep the two scores in the same data frame from the start:

```
library("tidyverse")

OKS <- OKS %>% 
  mutate(OKS_score_pre = OKS_score, 
         OKS_score_post = whatever_function(OKS_score)) %>%
  select(OKS_score_pre, OKS_score_post)
```

Comment: Thanks  @neakmaker - I see the logic for the second solution.

The function I used to get preopOKS is: 
`preopOKS <- filter(basic, ASSESS == 1)`

Where `basic` is the dataframe. `ASSESS` is the time point. But this ofcourse gives the preop scores for all columns (age,gender etc.). 

Within the dataframe, one of the columns are OKS_score. 

so to mutate into the main dataframe I try to use: 

'basic <- basic %>% 
  mutate(
    OKS_score_pre = filter(basic, ASSESS == 1)) '

But alas this doesn't work either :(

Answer (score 0):

Consider 2 columns:

```
cola<-runif(20,0,50)

colb<-runif(30,0,50)
```

Now we want equal column sizes. For that we can attribute the length of the column with maximum size to the other column. Then:

```
length(cola)<-length(colb)
```

Now,lets create a new dataframe. For simplicity lets first create a dataframe and name for each column, and combine the two single dataframe columns into one dataframe of two columns:

```
cola<-data.frame(a=cola)
colb<-data.frame(b=colb)


df<-data.frame(cola,colb)
```

Then to quickly plot as barplot side by side you can:

```
par(mfrow=c(1,2))   

barplot(df$a,legend.text = names(df[1]))
barplot(df$b,col="blue",beside=TRUE, legend.text = names(df[2]))
```

But using ggpplot you can do a better barplot.